# Unsupported operand types

Tags: laravel

```
This is app.php

'HTML' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
          'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,

this is view 
           {!! Form::select('country', ['' => 'Select'] +$countries,'',array('class'=>'form-control','id'=>'country','style'=>'width:350px;'));!!}
    i m getting Unsupported operand types  in the code 
 i m getting Unsupported operand types  in the code 
 i m getting Unsupported operand types  in the code 
 i m getting Unsupported operand types  in the code
```

i m getting Unsupported operand types  in the code 
     i m getting Unsupported operand types  in the code 
     i m getting Unsupported operand types  in the code 
     i m getting Unsupported operand types  in the code

Answer (score 0):

You've got a plus that is out of place:

```
['' => 'Select'] +$countries
```